# iPhone Crash Report : SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, navigationcontroller, sigabrt

I have a bug in my app that makes me crazy ! The main thread receives a SIGABRT message after trying to hide the navigationController toolbar.

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Does anyone have an idea from where it comes from ?
Thanks in advance.
AppPié

**EDIT :**

Here is the crash report :

```
Incident Identifier: 4DB9304F-9BCF-4EDA-9590-7B64AB1DAD25
CrashReporter Key:   2389e7e1ec88430fbde0957b840c1f635d1e6d53
Hardware Model:      iPhone1,2
Process:         Diamela [4297]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/68501259-E38C-44C6-A06C-C037F02724D9/Diamela.app/Diamela
Identifier:      Diamela
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-10-10 11:57:26.135 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de3ad0 0x35d5a000 + 563920
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de3abe 0x35d5a000 + 563902
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de3ab2 0x35d5a000 + 563890
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35dfad5e 0x35d5a000 + 658782
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de729e 0x35d5a000 + 578206
5   libgcc_s.1.dylib                0x358cfa58 0x358cc000 + 14936
6   CoreFoundation                  0x375215cc 0x374f9000 + 165324
7   CoreFoundation                  0x37521412 0x374f9000 + 164882
8   GraphicsServices                0x33e76d1c 0x33e72000 + 19740
9   UIKit                           0x3591d574 0x358d3000 + 304500
10  UIKit                           0x3591a550 0x358d3000 + 292176
11  Diamela                         0x00002ca2 0x1000 + 7330
12  Diamela                         0x00002c4c 0x1000 + 7244

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d8f974 0x35d5a000 + 219508
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35e5e2fc 0x35d5a000 + 1065724
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35e5dd68 0x35d5a000 + 1064296
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35e5d788 0x35d5a000 + 1062792
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de6970 0x35d5a000 + 575856
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35ddd2fc 0x35d5a000 + 537340

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d5b3b0 0x35d5a000 + 5040
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d5d894 0x35d5a000 + 14484
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37521f7c 0x374f9000 + 167804
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37521780 0x374f9000 + 165760
4   CoreFoundation                  0x37521504 0x374f9000 + 165124
5   CoreFoundation                  0x37521412 0x374f9000 + 164882
6   WebCore                         0x3318bd14 0x33070000 + 1162516
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de5b44 0x35d5a000 + 572228
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35dd77a4 0x35d5a000 + 513956

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3e74f308
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x35e75e14      r6: 0x00000146      r7: 0x2fdff950
    r8: 0x358cfd8c    r9: 0x0000c423     r10: 0x358cfe80     r11: 0x0014b870
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fdff950      lr: 0x35de3ac5      pc: 0x35de3ad0
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x5efff +Diamela armv6  <e585892558a634e58e1f00e60c614d0c> /var/mobile/Applications/68501259-E38C-44C6-A06C-C037F02724D9/Diamela.app/Diamela
  0x4ea000 -   0x4ebfff  dns.so armv6  <88b569311cca4a9593b2d670051860d1> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe29fff  dyld armv6  <617f6daf4103547c47a8407a2e0b90de> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30270000 - 0x3027bfff  ITSync armv6  <a451205e89373cbdf0832688085e8f72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x3027c000 - 0x3027efff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <f42bbbf67195a7b98d67ad021bba4784> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3027f000 - 0x3038dfff  CFNetwork armv6  <d6eeee83216ee9c553134f069f37cbc2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x303ef000 - 0x303f4fff  CaptiveNetwork armv6  <f41df4b358b77b29ff85e0eaea88ee1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x303f5000 - 0x30444fff  Security armv6  <cf625b4dc7ea928891313444ef64a7cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30445000 - 0x3055cfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <8968ff3f62d7780bb1bd75026a7628d0> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3055d000 - 0x30561fff  ApplePushService armv6  <0560b630d26e261e205fc58942e1885c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x3059d000 - 0x305a8fff  MobileWiFi armv6  <c7532e63e083a1dd2a0ef7352b85749d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x305aa000 - 0x30612fff  libvDSP.dylib armv6  <9d264733fc675943c082bd3b9b567b59> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x30613000 - 0x3064dfff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <beb473ce80390554bb4af21554522286> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3065c000 - 0x3066efff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <51e7bb18da9afa44a33e54e42fbd0707> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3066f000 - 0x306c6fff  CoreMedia armv6  <cd5e9398c161f129146931e888e1c92e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x306f0000 - 0x306fefff  libz.1.dylib armv6  <84592e96bae1a661374b0f9a5d03a3a0> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x306ff000 - 0x30729fff  PrintKit armv6  <74f9710fa01a33b5bb04c4aeabd6be7d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x3072e000 - 0x307d0fff  AVFoundation armv6  <da9d96f32791f51ecb439c5eaeeff59a> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x307d7000 - 0x3082afff  IOKit armv6  <20da5e822f21a8d0a7c5b3e149330efd> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x30831000 - 0x3083bfff  AccountSettings armv6  <eca67ab04f724e1fa7c6406c88e75433> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x30999000 - 0x309c5fff  DataAccess armv6  <8c045822d57a369835f5b40653a48838> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x309c6000 - 0x309f4fff  MIME armv6  <fac8f55c508ff476e07894af7abdb761> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x30a04000 - 0x30aa3fff  ProofReader armv6  <2734920b62f174c17aeeb15f371615ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x30ad6000 - 0x30b1afff  AddressBook armv6  <1f30c3370dad27331a491ba4b190813c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x30b3d000 - 0x30b9cfff  CoreAudio armv6  <ccc4bace0d6eca79a32ed84d566f72e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x32d7d000 - 0x32d89fff  libkxld.dylib armv6  <f74f359de7bbe3ccdc37fa6f332aebf4> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x32d95000 - 0x32e5cfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <429841269f8bcecd4ba3264a8725dad6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x32e5d000 - 0x32ecdfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6  <87b9bb47687902d9120d03d1da9eb9fc> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x32f0c000 - 0x32f1ffff  libmis.dylib armv6  <dba9c086b49bd9540930ff27211570d6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x33055000 - 0x33061fff  SpringBoardServices armv6  <fd0c472436b3306f5b56118c93c8a423> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x33062000 - 0x3306ffff  MobileBluetooth armv6  <2b68516e1321011a4efbee2947d463c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x33070000 - 0x338bffff  WebCore armv6  <aa3b6827f051da7a3494c9bee4ebe290> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x338c0000 - 0x338d4fff  MobileDeviceLink armv6  <19d66078f8cf19be558713c13612c7a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x33a6b000 - 0x33ab3fff  iCalendar armv6  <fbb717874ea0ede24454a5def644ab69> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x33ab4000 - 0x33ab4fff  Accelerate armv6  <cdde24a7ad004b2b2e600cd4f3ac5eb7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x33b32000 - 0x33b72fff  QuickLook armv6  <54400e0d48ec86c84e937e55790b9e54> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x33bbc000 - 0x33c0afff  CoreText armv6  <16c9582fdffb598178287c6ce9fd6897> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x33c16000 - 0x33d73fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv6  <aec6b54ffd532bb607aab4acbab679b6> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x33d76000 - 0x33d79fff  ActorKit armv6  <d3ec50b4a7f0257ef31baf37936dc275> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x33d85000 - 0x33e71fff  QuartzCore armv6  <77cd91ff21fe6c58c309f2c82eb95ca5> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33e72000 - 0x33e81fff  GraphicsServices armv6  <af20aba0ec96e7b7c42bb55ac763c784> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33ead000 - 0x33f6efff  ImageIO armv6  <0c1b6f466667ff345f2399d8142a9d10> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33f78000 - 0x33f79fff  CoreSurface armv6  <5e290514380c626e9b0f9f9985b9dc7a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x340ac000 - 0x340bffff  Notes armv6  <acf9e548948ecb299270c8398ef297a1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x34137000 - 0x34156fff  EAP8021X armv6  <fa56845b5396c3ebb368c2368331643c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x341ad000 - 0x341ebfff  ContentIndex armv6  <7f3334380acc72292571803f0b490189> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x343a0000 - 0x343bffff  Bom armv6  <f41bef81e23e2bff59155e5ce46762d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x343c0000 - 0x344bdfff  JavaScriptCore armv6  <3547c92c1efc0522b087e7f10eba7728> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x344be000 - 0x34500fff  ManagedConfiguration armv6  <397723a33c19c3487d304d69580acbfc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x34954000 - 0x34a5cfff  CoreData armv6  <6e3af4b4648ae695f8d4bc0bf5a9dba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x34a6e000 - 0x34a72fff  CertUI armv6  <57c499baf9d343a78fe1b43f0f3ef997> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x34b52000 - 0x34f1ffff  libLAPACK.dylib armv6  <0eb734c91165416224b98c943ff6476b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34f20000 - 0x35014fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv6  <01916d6784f4de8f3746978faae9c5fa> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x35015000 - 0x35022fff  CoreVideo armv6  <7b100fd5fdf98db1cd0f0649e7f6f316> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x35023000 - 0x3507dfff  MessageUI armv6  <21bb9d93911f7015b79aef9dc6df55ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x35087000 - 0x35148fff  AddressBookUI armv6  <fea72732451610277e22a667d35ad76d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x35151000 - 0x35272fff  Foundation armv6  <6bdeb19a1fcb93e2930dadb50416f881> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3529b000 - 0x352a6fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6  <6aa8a4ed0906a495d059ace9125f525d> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x352dc000 - 0x35342fff  libBLAS.dylib armv6  <11a3677a08175a30df1b3d66d7e0951a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x35406000 - 0x35406fff  vecLib armv6  <8f914b3e8a581d49fb21d2c0ff75be03> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x35407000 - 0x3540afff  MobileInstallation armv6  <456ed7fe6dd9fcd8e78df425085b1452> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x35541000 - 0x35547fff  MBX2D armv6  <fad4955cab36e0179df6f8f27d365b8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x35758000 - 0x35778fff  AppleAccount armv6  <0ef3f6564414f3ef030031ae25b28bbd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x35815000 - 0x3581afff  AssetsLibraryServices armv6  <224b3cf992a01814f91481244e3213eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3581b000 - 0x35877fff  libGLImage.dylib armv6  <7c1049f20c4e64591c09d3ac00c7d3ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x358bc000 - 0x358c3fff  liblockdown.dylib armv6  <f470dea180ddf23886df75eb256d3888> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x358cc000 - 0x358cffff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6  <bed95ed187350ce27d22ed241ef892ea> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x358d3000 - 0x35d4ffff  UIKit armv6  <14ec6c926b8bda71b73136f6e1a6ac1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x35d5a000 - 0x35e98fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6  <70571c1e697e2ae7f7a9b1a499453bb6> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x35f7e000 - 0x35fc2fff  VideoToolbox armv6  <101dbbcd34cc3231a8be3fd6392556aa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x35fdb000 - 0x36162fff  CoreGraphics armv6  <9a1d72fa9549d83abc1e735ba37a4dc2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x36167000 - 0x36178fff  DataAccessExpress armv6  <c112bd2791eb706526db25407ec117d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x36179000 - 0x36255fff  WebKit armv6  <83da207070be989ba81dba3a83d5206a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x36269000 - 0x36278fff  OpenGLES armv6  <37eda5ddcff210dd321157da35a87a5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x363f3000 - 0x363f9fff  MobileKeyBag armv6  <2d83bf6a43bab972d77a1a6e0f3b03d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x363fa000 - 0x36483fff  Message armv6  <9ed4944d998f99e69ba81afdda659bee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x365db000 - 0x365f9fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6  <9c94634beea733e754dc115737b6e63c> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x36746000 - 0x3683cfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <9c44d05cc67f1ebabd795903e581724e> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3683e000 - 0x36888fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv6  <cfc94cfa17958f2f94c9eff208a7dace> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x36889000 - 0x368b4fff  MobileSync armv6  <b42cf746d993e6765d432edf47987835> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x368b5000 - 0x3692dfff  EventKit armv6  <c1fb82d645d3bf1f2e0558cc884712e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x3694c000 - 0x3694ffff  libAccessibility.dylib armv6  <74e0f77cc276a9412be268c795fdcbca> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x36955000 - 0x36a1ffff  Celestial armv6  <11172a6ee53bdf067548cd4496bc5fe0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x36a20000 - 0x36a2cfff  WebBookmarks armv6  <5d1eb10d851d0362e304d9d95f016df1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x36a2d000 - 0x36a30fff  CrashReporterSupport armv6  <00bc60f690e6328b64e7a7b718edf45a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x36a31000 - 0x36a74fff  CoreTelephony armv6  <cabbce0fa7630065dc7e7d3ca3bc616c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x36c1c000 - 0x36c26fff  AggregateDictionary armv6  <f7429444c955e4f13c6761d20032ab52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x36c2b000 - 0x36de1fff  AudioToolbox armv6  <bb65e8ed531fe5923eb8ac00a7c0d87d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x36de2000 - 0x36e16fff  AppSupport armv6  <783e14db9585fd063c0c2a755cd121b6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x36e17000 - 0x36e2dfff  PersistentConnection armv6  <006723906b8ac250c1681a1821fbe94d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x37141000 - 0x37184fff  SystemConfiguration armv6  <207f362e707871e74a292cfd1ea7893d> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x372aa000 - 0x37477fff  MediaToolbox armv6  <21ceabd0e5de17ad4e883c85fcd34d51> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x37478000 - 0x3747dfff  IOSurface armv6  <ffd66ca04dfe7d382d6961f0df3839ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3748d000 - 0x374f8fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <eccd1d7183e73587b2c0aa5755a19c39> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x374f9000 - 0x375e4fff  CoreFoundation armv6  <ab0eac0ddd5b4ae1bf8541116e3c0bd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3760a000 - 0x3760bfff  DataMigration armv6  <d2de7c0db77278484236669c2cdccabb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x37731000 - 0x37736fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv6  <bd1c480607cc286288db1ca1aec64180> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x377f6000 - 0x37817fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv6  <22c6da37f3adf325f99c3a0494e04c02> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x37992000 - 0x37999fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv6  <de9b417e7278742e90b30b1ad45f31fa> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
```

Comment: post the crash log as well as some code snippets

Comment: Add a line before this with `NSLog(@"NavCtrl %@", [self.navigationController description]);`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's likely that you're over-releasing one of the buttons on the toolbar.

I don't think it'll help you in this case, but you really need to symbolicate your crash log. That way you'll be able to see the line and file that the program crashes on.